# What are open source alternatives for the Esri City Engine Software?

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations

I am looking for open source software similar to [ESRI City Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CityEngine) and currently going through [open source software directory](http://opensourcesoftwaredirectory.com/Graphics/3D-Modeling).

[About ESRI City Engine (Quick introduction)](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/cityengine/about)

We want to make few historical places in 3D format & I heard that in some cases its difficult to integrate with other software (i.e. Esri City engine to Google earth and vice verse etc)

Most of the spatial data is in PostgreSQL/PostGIS . Hence looking for alternative so any open source software included 3 D editing facility  will be great.

Comment: could you elaborate on what City Engine does in general and what you want to do in particular?

Comment: @iant Currently we need to make 3 D models for important parts of the city & few extra things .I will update the question soon.

Comment: CityGML is OpenSource - http://www.citygml.org/ mainly used for European Cities (Germany, Austria use it) View Examples here http://www.citygml.org/index.php?id=1539

Comment: @Mapperz thanks for the reply I am going though the links : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look at [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) which is the defacto standard open source 3D modeling program with a huge community and tons of tutorials out on the web.

Here is a [tuturial about creating a cityscape](http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/how-to-create-a-city/) in Blender.

Answer (score 3):

[3D City DB](http://www.3dcitydb.net/3dcitydb/welcome/) may be an option for you.

It is "open source and released under the terms of LGPL" and supports CityGML, Oracle and PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Virtual Terrain Project (vterrain.org).  This is designed to deal with large and complex terrain models, and is fully open source.  You might still want to use Blender for custom buildings, but VTP has procedural building modeling built in.

Answer (score 0):

you can try sketchup together with Google Earth, you can position the 3D objects correctly in sketchup then create a kml with terrain and 3 objects, you can streem 3d into a kml network link, this will work nicely if you do not have a complex setup