# making a interactive map

Tags: web-mapping

I have a georeferenced map that gives a view of 3D,which I have created in ArcScene and exported as jpeg(or tif if necessary).What I want to do is create a interactive map that allows user to click on a certain building on that image and a marker that shows the information about that building appears...and also the options of zooming,panning and scale displaying would add favour to the map...
Is there a way that one can give the coordinate extent of that image and marker be displayed on exact certain LatLong?Or is there other way around to deal with it please suggest...I looked upon internet and came up with nothing

Comment: Not sure but check similar question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58133/looking-for-open-source-software-similiar-to-esri-city-engine